# Safe way to change the priority of an NSOperation

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, macos

Is there a safe way to change the priority of an NSOperation that is already enqueued in an NSOperationQueue? If the operation hasn't started yet there is no problem, but if it is already executing I get an NSInvalidArgumentException.

Comment: Can you show us the stack trace and contents of the exception? It's a little hard to diagnose at the moment

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're not supposed to alter an NSOperation once it has been enqueued.  According to Apple's [Threading Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW38):

> Important: You should never modify an
>   operation object after it has been
>   added to a queue. While waiting in a
>   queue, the operation could execute at
>   any time. Changing its status while it
>   is executing could have adverse
>   effects. You can use the methods of
>   the operation object to determine if
>   the operation is running, waiting to
>   run, or already finished.

Comment: Updated link: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW38

Answer (score 1):

According to [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/conceptual/concurrencyprogrammingguide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW31) we should be able to change the priority

```
For operations added to a queue, execution order is determined first by the
readiness of the queued operations and then by their relative priority. 
Readiness is determined by an operation’s dependencies on other operations, 
but the priority level is an attribute of the operation object itself. 
By default, all new operation objects have a “normal” priority, but you 
can increase or decrease that priority as needed by calling the object’s 
setQueuePriority: method.
```

Answer (score 0):

On the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOperation/setQueuePriority:) there is no warning about not changing the priority after the operation has started and there is no mention about raised exceptions.

In fact changing the priority of a running operation simply has no effect. Maybe you're making something wrong elsewhere?